# 2018 Subaru Outback with 25,000 miles and cam leak

Tags: subaru

I have a one year old Subaru Outback, 25000 miles, with a cam leak.  Initially, the diagnosis was a passenger side valve leak which was fixed (under warranty).  At the next oil change, the mechanic showed me that there was still a small oil leak and recommended that I get it addressed while still under warranty.   The car has been with the dealer for four days.  The leak was evidently fixed and then they found it was still leaking and had to seal another area.  I’m concerned that this has occurred within the first year of owning the car.  Oil usage has been normal.  Do I have a lemon on my hands?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you are asking.  We only offer mechanical advice here; not opinions or legal advice.

Have it fixed properly under warranty by the dealer. I doubt you have a "lemon", but depending on your state of residence you may be able to start lemon law proceedings after the third unsuccessful repair attempt.  This varies from state-to-state, but it always assumes the vehicle was purchased new.

The mere threat of such may inspire the dealer to pay more attention to your repair.  Be polite, but firm.  And you must have your "ducks in a row" - google "lemon law" for your state and find out what your rights are before squaring off face-to-face with the service adviser, manager, or GM.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the response and insight.  Once the issue is fixed (assuming it’s done well), is this leak something that often reoccurs?  I’ve looked at several sites where Subaru’s and oil leaks are often mentioned.